# Discord.js permissionOverwrites on creating a channel WON'T change the permissions?

Tags: discord.js

I'm writing a Discord.js bot on Node.js (Discord.js v12 stable), and I want it to change/overwrite permissions of the channel which was created.

Following code, I've tried...

```
message.guild.channels.create('channelname', {
  type: 'text',
  permissionOverwrites: [{
      id: message.guild.id,
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
    {
      id: message.author.id,
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
  ],
});
```

... seemed to just ignore the permissionOverwrites: [ ] part and continue the code without any errors. The code above is actually an example of discord.js guide's website (https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#adding-overwrites). I'm a little confused here, as it shows no errors at all and kinda just ignores the permissionOverwrites part.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the permissions after the channel has been created? e.g. timeout for 100ms and then do channel.overwritePermissions

Comment: Nope, just adding the created channel to a category and sending a message into it.

Comment: @ApocalypseCalculator but what is permissionOverwrites: [ ] at creating a channel there for then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing:

```js
message.guild.channels.create('channelname', {
type: 'text'
}).then(channel => {
   channel.overwritePermissions([
    {
        id: message.guild.id,
        deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
    },
    {
        id: message.author.id,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
    }]);
});
```

Comment: That didn't work either. It just won't change the permissions!

Comment: are you sure everything else is correct? does your bot have the permissions? does anything show up in audit log?

Comment: @L3g3nd4ry I figured out your problem, the formatting of the permissions object is incorrect because you added an extra comma, I've edited my answer :)

Comment: I can demonstrate to you what happens. I can show you the output, the exact script and actually I just tried the same script in a different server, and it worked there. In all out of 1 server the same script works. What is this about? Is this a issue on Discord's end? All bots have Administrator permission and the roles are also placed pretty high. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: if it only doesnt work on one server it probably is a Discord error. did anything show up in audit log?

Comment: @L3g3nd4ry I forgot to fix the second extra comma, I'm stupid. I hope my newly edited answer works lmao

Comment: I'm so sorry for wasting your time (lol), I messed up something on my side. THe issue was that I had the setParent there with issues, and a lot of then() things which I have fixed now. The thing was, that if you don't setParent the channel BEFORE you change the permissions, the channel will synchronize permissions with the category.