# Hiding channel with Djs12

Tags: discord.js

I need to lock a **text** channel, so @everyone cannot see that, but message.author can. I have this code, but everyone can see the channel (and in the channel properties everyone hasn't got permission for send messages or send TTS messages, but above that everything is [/])

```
message.guild.channels.create(desc, {
                    type: 'text',
                    permissionOverwrites: [
                        {
                            id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
                            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
                        },
                        {
                            id: message.author.id,
                            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                        },
                    ],
                })
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`PermissionOverwrites`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/PermissionOverwrites?scrollTo=id) typedef requires a [`Snowflake`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake) (in this case, a role or user ID). However, [`RoleManager.everyone`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=everyone) returns a [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role). There are two ways to solve this issue:

- Simply just use the [`id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=id) property of the role

```js
{
 id: message.guild.roles.everyone.id,
 deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
},
```

- Use [`message.guild.id`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=id). Fun fact, the @everyone role shares the same ID as the guild it's in

```js
{
 id: message.guild.id,
 deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
},
```

Comment: Hi @Lioness100, and thank you for your answer. This is not the correct answer, since I tried all your soultions. It still doesn't working.

Comment: That's weird, as I'm pretty sure the syntax is correct. [This might be related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418834/discord-js-permissionoverwrites-on-creating-a-channel-wont-change-the-permission)

Comment: It didn't help me, since the user had the same problem what I have, but other developers  cannot help him.